# Canon Remote Switch RS60 E3 not working as expected

Tags: canon, long-exposure, remote, canon-60d, bulb-mode

Canon Remote Switch RS60 E3 is not working as expected on my Canon 60D when I try to take a long exposure shot. Here is what is happening-

I set the camera to bulb mode and lock the remote to start the exposure. Let's say I plan to keep the shutter open for 2 minutes. After 2 minutes, I unlock the remote but the shutter continues to stay open and the exposure goes on. I have to manually pull the remote out of the camera to close the shutter. Can someone please share some inputs on what's happening here? Is it a faulty lock switch on the remote? The remote works fine when I am just pressing it to take a shot and not locking it for longer periods.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you using mirror lock-up?

Comment: If that were the problem then pulling the cord out would not solve it. It would *appear* to solve it only if pulling it out was perfectly timed at 30 seconds after the shutter button was initially pressed.

Comment: Hmm. Unless pulling it out allowed the half press and full press wires to contact the full press and ground springs on the jack and simulate another full press.

Comment: Nope. The shutter wire is on the tip and the ground ring is on the other end. http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/

Comment: No, I have the mirror lock-up in disabled mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If pulling the cord of the RS60-E3 out of the camera jack solves the problem then the problem is not in the camera, it is with the RS60-E3.

What happens if you immediately plug the cord back in? Does the shutter open back up for another exposure? It sounds like the shutter button is just getting stuck and takes a while to fully release. If you only recently bought the switch I would see if it could be exchanged for another one.